# Magento : File Upload Problem in Magento Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1, magento-connect-manager, file-upload

I have install succesfully new magento 1.9.3.1 from my control panel, When I try to upload file zip file (tgz) from Magento connect manager, after 100% upload... it say no file was uploaded.

It is really frustating after several question with my web host but non is solve.

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP Settings and the size of your package.

Make sure the below two settings are set above the size you are uploading

```
post_max_size = 2M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

By default it is set to 2MB. If your package size is greater then increase this the values and restart PHP.